# Adobe Flash in JxBrowser not working after upgrade from version 6.20 to 7.9

Tags: swing, flash, jxbrowser

I have a Java Swing application that is using JxBrowser. Now, I am upgrading JxBrowser from version 6.20 to 7.9. When loading a web page with Adobe Flash content in the old version, it works just fine. The Flash content is shown without any problem. With JxBrowser 7.9, I get: Right click to run Adobe Flash Player.

[Page with Adobe Flash in JxBrowser 7.9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiaQi.png)

What do I need to do so that it just runs like before? I tried this:

```
        browser.settings().enablePlugins();
```

But that didn't help. What am I missing?

Comment: I don’t know which JxBrowser version maps to which Chromium version, but perhaps [this change](https://www.chromium.org/flash-roadmap#TOC-Flash-Disabled-by-Default-Target:-Chrome-76---July-2019-) is relevant. And, well, you should be prepared for [this upcoming change](https://www.chromium.org/flash-roadmap#TOC-Flash-Player-blocked-as-out-of-date-Target:-All-Chrome-versions---Jan-2021-) for sure…

Comment: JxBrowser 7.9 uses Chromium 79 and Flash was disabled in Chromium 76+. I believe that's the root cause of the behavior you observe.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I guess we just have to get away from Flash.